# Why doesn't NUnit have an IsElementOf/IsOneOf constraint?

Tags: unit-testing, collections, nunit, dsl

I am not working with NUnit directly, but am looking to borrow some of its ideas in a different context.

One particularly elegant idea is the constraints machinery which lets you write a unit test of the form:

```
Assert.That(aValue, Is.GreaterThan(2.0) & Is.LessThan(5.0));
```

You can also test that a value is in some range:

```
Assert.That(aValue, Is.InRange(2.0, 5.0));
```

However, there does not seem to be a way to test that `aValue` is one of a collection of allowed values:

```
Assert.That(aValue, Is.OneOf(aCollection));
```

Is it just not that common in a unit test?  Does it point to some problem with my unit tests?
Does everyone just inject aValue into some dummy one element collection and then use `Is.SubsetOf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of NUnit (3.13) has a native method for this: `Is.AnyOf(params object[] expected)`

You can use it like this:

```
Assert.That(result, Is.AnyOf("red", "green", "blue"));
Assert.That(result, Is.Not.AnyOf("black", "white"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assertion API's is all about readability, and there is no benefit in readability of having Is.OneOf(collection) to this:

```
Assert.That(collection.Contains(value));
```

It is readable and clear, so duplicating each case in Assersion API isn't right if it brings nothing. As far as you can see there is no easy way of writing alternative to Is.InRange and Is.GreaterThan + Is.LessThan is more redable than

```
Assert.That(value > 2.0 && value < 5.0);
//compared to
Assert.That(value, Is.GraterThan(2.0).And.Is.LessThan(5.0));
```

Comment: But surely the same logic can be applied to `Is.OneOf(collection)`: you can combine it with other constraints:  `Assert.That(value, Is.OneOf(Foo).And.Is.Not.OneOf(Bar))`.  Also `collection.Contains(value)` puts the focus on the `collection`, rather than the `value`.

Comment: It can be both a good and a bad. It depends on what you are testing that some collection has a value or some value exists in collection. And it isn't the same logic, I wasn't talking about combining constraints. I can understand combining constraints for numbers, but it is strange for me to see. Is.OneOf(Foo).And.Is.Not.OneOf(Bar)). As for me there are two assersions in one and this is not a very good approach in writing unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

@Lambdageek;

```
Assert.That(aCollection, Has.Member(aValue) 
Assert.That(aCollection, Has.No.Member(aValue)
```

has been around for awhile. There is a bunch of other useful collection constraints also, decently documented [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionConstraints&r=2.5.10).

In addition to the readability, you also get a much more useful level of feedback when something fails. Worth the miniscule additional effort, IMO.

**EDIT**

```
    [Test]
    public void Test() {
        var c = new[] {"one", "two"};
        Assert.That(c, Has.Member("three"));
    }

Test failed:
  Expected: collection containing "three"
  But was:  < "one", "two" >
    Tests.cs(73,0): at ...Test()
```

Cheers,
Berryl

## Poor Man's constraint

```
public static class TestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsOneOf<T>(this T candidate, IEnumerable<T> expected) {
        if (expected.Contains(candidate)) return true;

        var msg = string.Format("Expected one of: '{0}'. Actual: {1}", ", "._insertBetween(expected.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x))), candidate);
        Assert.Fail(msg);
        return false;
    }

    private static string _insertBetween(this string delimiter, IEnumerable<string> items)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (builder.Length != 0)
            {
                builder.Append(delimiter);
            }
            builder.Append(item);
        }
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<string> GenerateSplits(this string str, params char[] separators)
    {
        foreach (var split in str.Split(separators))
            yield return split;
    }

}
```

## Failing test

```
    [Test]
    public void IsOneOf_IfCandidateNotInRange_Error()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> expected = new[] { "red", "green", "blue" };
        const string candidate = "yellow";
        Assert.That(candidate.IsOneOf(expected));
    }

IsOneOf_IfCandidateNotInRange_Error' failed:
Expected one of: 'red, green, blue'. Actual: yellow
```

Comment: Well as I mentioned in reply to @Restuta's answer: in my opinion, `Assert.That(x, Has.Member(y))` puts the emphasis on `x`, when what I'm really testing is `y`.  In particular, I want error messages telling me about the actual value of `aValue` if the unit test fails, not the actual value of `aCollection`.

Comment: @Lambdageek - see my edit above. I thought you *were* looking to assert that aValue was in a collection, but perhaps I am misunderstanding you. If not, what exactly are you looking to assert, and how should the message from a failing test read? If so, what about the existing constraint is lacking?

Comment: I want to check that `aValue` which is computed by some function:   `aValue = Foo()` is one of a set of allowable values: `Assert.That(aValue, Is.OneOf({"red", "green", "blue"});`  So I want the error message to say: "Expected one of 'red', 'green', 'blue'.  Actual: 'yellow'"

Comment: @Lambdageek. Got it, and no, I don't see something like that in NUnit. I *do* keep a static class of TestExtensions around for those (rare) times when I need more than NUnit straight up gives, so writing the extension you want would look something like the code I added to my answer. It really isn't difficult to do either, once you have got some of the helper methods in place (props to Skeet for that). Cheers